# Problems with EF7 connection on Azure App Service

Tags: azure, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, entity-framework-core, asp.net-core-1.0

I am running an ASP.NET Core app with EF7 on an Azure App Service that has been running for 7 months. I recently upgraded from RC2 to 1.0 and since then, the app has started crashing after about 36-48 hours. Restarting the app temporarliy solves the problem.

The response from the server is a blank 500-response (even if error pages are enabled).

Looking through the logs I found the following errors in stdout:

```
fail: Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.QueryCompiler[1]
  An exception occurred in the database while iterating the results of a query.
  System.InvalidOperationException: ExecuteReader requires an open and available Connection. The connection's current state is closed.
     at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.ValidateCommand(String method, Boolean async)
     at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.RunExecuteReader(CommandBehavior cmdBehavior, RunBehavior runBehavior, Boolean returnStream, String method, TaskCompletionSource`1 completion, Int32 timeout, Task& task, Boolean asyncWrite)
     at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.RunExecuteReader(CommandBehavior cmdBehavior, RunBehavior runBehavior, Boolean returnStream, String method)
     at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior behavior, String method)
     at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Storage.Internal.RelationalCommand.Execute(IRelationalConnection connection, String executeMethod, IReadOnlyDictionary`2 parameterValues, Boolean openConnection, Boolean closeConnection)
     at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Storage.Internal.RelationalCommand.ExecuteReader(IRelationalConnection connection, IReadOnlyDictionary`2 parameterValues, Boolean manageConnection)
     at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.QueryingEnumerable.Enumerator.MoveNext()
     at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.QueryMethodProvider.<_ShapedQuery>d__3`1.MoveNext()
     at System.Linq.Enumerable.WhereSelectEnumerableIterator`2.MoveNext()
     at System.Linq.Enumerable.Single[TSource](IEnumerable`1 source)
     at lambda_method(Closure , QueryContext )
     at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.QueryCompiler.<>c__DisplayClass19_1`1.<CompileQuery>b__1(QueryContext qc)
```

followed by

```
fail: Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.QueryCompiler[1]
  An exception occurred in the database while iterating the results of a query.
  System.InvalidOperationException: Internal connection fatal error. Error state: 15, Token : 16
     at System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.TryRun(RunBehavior runBehavior, SqlCommand cmdHandler, SqlDataReader dataStream, BulkCopySimpleResultSet bulkCopyHandler, TdsParserStateObject stateObj, Boolean& dataReady)
     at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataReader.TryConsumeMetaData()
     at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataReader.get_MetaData()
     at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.FinishExecuteReader(SqlDataReader ds, RunBehavior runBehavior, String resetOptionsString)
     at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.RunExecuteReaderTds(CommandBehavior cmdBehavior, RunBehavior runBehavior, Boolean returnStream, Boolean async, Int32 timeout, Task& task, Boolean asyncWrite, SqlDataReader ds, Boolean describeParameterEncryptionRequest)
     at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.RunExecuteReader(CommandBehavior cmdBehavior, RunBehavior runBehavior, Boolean returnStream, String method, TaskCompletionSource`1 completion, Int32 timeout, Task& task, Boolean asyncWrite)
     at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.RunExecuteReader(CommandBehavior cmdBehavior, RunBehavior runBehavior, Boolean returnStream, String method)
     at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior behavior, String method)
     at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Storage.Internal.RelationalCommand.Execute(IRelationalConnection connection, String executeMethod, IReadOnlyDictionary`2 parameterValues, Boolean openConnection, Boolean closeConnection)
     at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Storage.Internal.RelationalCommand.ExecuteReader(IRelationalConnection connection, IReadOnlyDictionary`2 parameterValues, Boolean manageConnection)
     at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.QueryingEnumerable.Enumerator.MoveNext()
     at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.QueryMethodProvider.<_ShapedQuery>d__3`1.MoveNext()
     at System.Linq.Enumerable.WhereSelectEnumerableIterator`2.MoveNext()
     at System.Linq.Enumerable.Single[TSource](IEnumerable`1 source)
     at lambda_method(Closure , QueryContext )
     at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.QueryCompiler.<>c__DisplayClass19_1`1.<CompileQuery>b__1(QueryContext qc)
```

This occurs at a step in the owin-pipeline that loads tenant data before the MVC framework is hooked in.

I am using the built-in dependency injection to resolve my DbContext.

[Startup.cs](https://github.com/severisv/MyTeam/blob/master/src/MyTeam/Startup.cs)

[Line where error occurs](https://github.com/severisv/MyTeam/blob/master/src/MyTeam/Services/Application/CacheHelper.cs#L77)

Comment: are you getting the same issue when the app is run locally ?

Comment: No, but I have not had the app running locally for the same amount of time it takes for the app to crash on Azure